# Fibre bundle and Borel construction of compact groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

if $G$ is any compact group and $H$ is closed subgroup of $G$,
then $G/H\rightarrow X_{H}\rightarrow X_{G}$ is a fibre bundle? ($X_G=X\times _{G}E=\left( X\times E\right)
/G $ is orbit space where $X,G$-space and $G$ acts freely on $E$ contractible space and $G$ acts on $X\times E$ with $g\left( x,e\right) =\left( gx,ge\right) $)

Comment: You need to assume that $EG\to EG/G$ is a principal $G$--bundle, which doesn't follow from your assumptions (take $EG$ to be $G$ with the indiscrete topology to get a counterexample).  Then you can take $EH = EG$, and your sequence is just the pullback of $G/H \to EG/H\to EG/G$ along the map $X_G \to EG/G$.